# Trig identities: write answer in terms of sine and cosine

Tags: trigonometry

I attached an image but just in case it doesn't show up properly, the prompt is to write $$\frac{\csc(x)\cot(x)}{\sec(x)}$$ in terms of sine and cosine.

What I don't understand is that the prompt is to write the answer in terms of sine and cosine but the answer when I checked is B, or $\cot^2(x)$. Maybe I am simply rubbish with trig identities (ok, not maybe), but this answer especially doesn't make sense. Can anyone explain to me with well thought out steps why this is the answer?

Comment: Maybe they just wanted you to convert to sines and cosines, simplify, and then compare the answer to $\cot^2t$ and decide if it is equivalent to your answer.

Comment: If "$\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x}$" (or "$\left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)^2$") is one of the available answer choices, then it's entirely possible that the answer key has an error. These things happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$$
$$ \cot(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$
$$\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$
$$\frac{\csc(x)\cot(x)}{\sec(x)}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sin(x)}\
\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}}{\frac{1}{\cos(x)}}=\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)}$$
$$=\cot^2(x)$$

Comment: Hey RAM, I get your logic until the second to last line. How the heck do you go from ((csc(x))(cot(x)))/(sec(x)) to (cos^2(x))/(sin^2(x))?

Comment: Check my answer i re edited that for you

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense now.